# Xamarin.Ios does not deploy to iphone-simulator

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, virtual-machine, simulator

I have a notebook with windows installed and a virtual machine of MacOs Catalina.
Connecting the Mac to Visual Studio on windows works without a problem but when I want to run the Xamarin.Ios Project the simulator boots and after some seconds the error

> "could not launch the app (bundle_name) on the device iOS 13.3 - iPhone 11: The request to open (bundle_name) failed.

occures.

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToDHS.png)

The latest version of XCode (11.3.1) and Visualstudio 2019 are both installed on the virtual machine.

Sometimes another error occures on the virtual machine which says that springboard quit unexpected. Don't know if it has something to do with this problem

[Here is the error for the springboard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOVxW.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this? I looked it up online but I can't find a working solution.

Comment: Hi , you also need to install xamarin ios in Mac . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/#mac-installation By the way , you'd better use a physical mac to develop , I'm not sure a virtual Mac can work .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Xamarin ios is already installed on my mac

Comment: OK , if using Non-Mac Hardware , it's no possible to do that . Suggest that using physical mac to develop .

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. I changed my provisioning profile from distribution to development and it fixed .